# Why does `insert` not insert colorized text?

Tags: text-properties

For instance, why does `(insert #("abc" 0 3 (face (:foreground "red"))))` not insert red text?

Comment: I'll let another forum participant explain the "why" ... But, how about using?:  `(insert (propertize "abc" 'face '(:foreground "red")))`  See also `add-text-properties` and `put-text-property` as alternative methods to colorize text ...; and, this can also be done with overlays if so desired ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably try that in the `*scratch*` buffer or any other buffer with active `font-lock-mode`.

In such a buffer the faces are immediately adapted to the rules prescribed by the variable `font-lock-keywords`.

Use the property `font-lock-face` instead of `face` in those buffers.

The modified version of your example would be:

```el
(insert #("abc" 0 3 (font-lock-face (:foreground "red"))))
```

`font-lock-face` properties are directly translated into `face` properties by `font-lock-mode`. No fontification rules are applied to those stretches of text.

Side-note: `lisp-interaction-mode` is derived from `emacs-lisp-mode` that activates `font-lock-mode`.

Comment: It's really easy to forget this.

Comment: Indeed, I tried it in the `*scratch*` buffer.